# How to extract date from file and make it as a folder in ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

I have a file name abcd_050420211200.csv

My requirement is I can to extract date part from filename and make it as a folder structure
ex:2021/04/05/abcd_050420211200.csv.

I have extracted date part from file using split but result is in 050420211200 I was not able to make it in proper date format and making them in a folder format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took set variable activity Splitting filename where it finds underscore,

```
@split(item().name,'_')[1]
```

[image]

Took another set variable activity and splitting the output of above activity as date with index number.

```
@substring(variables('infilename'),0,8)
```

[image]

Took another set variable activity and further spllitting the output of previous activity to day, month and year wise as followes:

```
for Day: @substring(variables('datesplit'),0,2)
for Month: @substring(variables('datesplit'),2,2)
for Year: @substring(variables('datesplit'),4)
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Now concat cat all three values with the `/` sign **value3 is year variable, value2 is month variable, value1 is day variable.**

```
@concat(variables('value3'),'/',variables('value2'),'/',variables('value1'))
```

[image]

and now pass this value to sin by creating parameter

create parameters to sink dataset.
[image]

Pass dynamic values of parameters created to filename and folder name
[image]

now pass the date variable to folder name dataset property
[image]

**OUTPUT**
[image]

Comment: Thank you Pratik This Solution is Helped but @substring is not Accepting 2 Parameters Which is used for year any suggestions for it?

Comment: try with `@substring(variables('var'),4,4)`

Comment: Thank you It's working AS EXpected